# How to send CloudFormation Outputs to an SNS topic? (Or any other endpoint, actually?)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns

I have a CloudFormation template with an Output section. I would like to have the output sent to an SNS topic, but all I found so far is either the notificationsARNs, which sends the stack events (and not the outputs)

Answer (score 0):

You can use boto3 to get the outputs of cloudformation and send it to sns

```
cloudformation_client = session.client('cloudformation')
response = cloudformation_client.describe_stacks(
    StackName=StackName,
)
outputs_list = response['Stacks'][0]['Outputs']
```

and then post it to sns
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sns.html

Comment: It's a workable solution, but what I wanted is for the stack to send it by itself, not querying it from another service and then sending it. Something like adding a custom resource